# The query on SQL Server is executed wrongly

Tags: c#

I have a problem with this query as it deletes all the rows for the CNP selected and I have to delete only the one with `Nume_Excursie='Vacanta1'`.

When I run the query without the first line it finds only a row, but when I run the entire query it deletes all the rows and I really don't know why.

- Client (ID_Client, CNP, Date, ...)
- Period (ID, ID_Client, ID_Excursie,..)
- Excursie (ID_Excursie, Nume_Excursie,..)

[image]

```
delete from perioada 
where 
    Perioada.ID_Client = 
        (select distinct p.ID_Client 
         from Perioada p 
         join Client c on p.ID_Client = c.ID_Client 
         where (c.CNP = 'xxxxx..' 
           and p.ID_Excursie = (select e.id_excursie 
                                from Excursie e 
                                where e.Nume_Excursie = 'Vacanta1')))
```

Comment: Why are you deleting from perioada and matching on ID_Client  instead of matching on ID_Perioda? ID_Client isn't unique (your link shows both rows have values of 3) but their ID_Perioda's are unique.

Comment: ID_Client (is unique- primary key in Client) is foreign key in Perioada. In the interface i have to use only CNP and Name_Excursie. This is why i wrote the query in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong here but it looks like Period is one-to-many with Client in your database so it will have multiple clients per period; do you even need to query the client table considering this fact?

You will also want to delete from Period using it's primary key, ID_Period, not on it's Client FK since it's not distinct in the Period table. Here's some SQL I threw together that tries to do this:

```
DELETE FROM Period
WHERE Id_period =
(
    SELECT Id_Period 
    FROM Period p 
    JOIN Excursie e on p.ID_Excursie = e.Id_excursie 
    WHERE e.Nume_Excursie = 'Vacanta1'
)
```

If the limitation of the Client being "xxxxx.." is required we can now just modify the inner selection.

```
DELETE FROM Period
WHERE Id_period =
(
    SELECT Id_Period 
    FROM Perioad p 
    JOIN Excursie e on p.ID_Excursie = e.Id_excursie 
    JOIN Client c on c.ID_Client = p.ID_Client
    WHERE e.Nume_Excursie = 'Vacanta1'
    AND c.CNP = 'xxxxx..'
)
```

Comment: Excursie is many to many with Client by Period. It's true that Period is one-to-many with Client.

Comment: After having re-read your edit I believe the 2nd answer should work for your purposes, let me know if there's any problems with it